# Booting a usb windows to go drive from hyper v

Tags: hyper-v, windows-10, usb-boot

I provisioned and made a bootable windows 10 to go drive using the instructions here

http://www.admin-magazine.com/Articles/Putting-Windows-8-on-a-USB-Drive

and tried to boot it with a gen-2 vm by attatching it to the scsi controller as a physical hd[image]

But I get the error

Boot failed. Efi SCSI device.

PS - yes, the usb partition is offline - otherwise it wouldn't show up in settings.

Comment: May I ask, why you require direct VM boot from USB instead of keeping vhdx on USB?

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned , it is an OS running on USB disk .

Generally , if it is an OS running on physical server , then , the OS can not be used for VM directly .

This is why we need the feature P2V .

Also , It seems that the USB disk is based on BIOS . But , the VM is a GEN2 VM , it is based on UEFI .

If you want to run that OS on VM , you may consider P2V or attach USB to VM then install OS directly on USB disk.